# SML: subtract one list from another list

Tags: list, sml, subtraction

What is the easiest way to subtract one list from another? Do I need to use ListPair to solve this task? Notic that I need to compare ROWS, not single elements. For instance, there are two lists "L1" and "L2":

```
L1 = 
[(1, 2, 3), 
(4, 5, 6)]

L2 = 
[(1, 2, 3), 
(4, 5, 6),  
(3, 2, 3]
```

I need to get "L3" by applying `L3 = L2-L1`:

```
L3 = 
[(3, 2, 3)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to remove the elements from L2 which are also in L1, but only once per occurrence in L1?

Comment: What do you intend if L1 is not a prefix of L2?

Comment: It`s correct. But there might be multiple occurences, which should be removed as well.

Comment: But in your example, you did not remove multiple occurrences of 3 and 2 in L2.

Comment: You say multiple occurrences should be removed, however your example contains multiple occurrences of 2 and 3, which you leave. Your example currently just removes the prefix.

Comment: I mean that I want to remove ROWS, not particular elements. In the above-example, "3 2 3" is not equal to "1 2 3" or "4 5 6". Therefore, this row should be the output of a function in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to remove the elements in L2 which are also in L1, but only once per occurrence.

A simple solution might involve a helper function to tell you if an element was found in L1, along with the rest of L1 with this element removed.

```
fun remFirst _ [] rest = (false, rev rest)
  | remFirst x (y::ys) rest =
    if x = y then
        (true, rev rest @ ys)
    else
        remFirst x ys (y :: rest)
```

Now you can iterate through L2, discarding elements each time remFirst returns true, and then proceeding with the rest of the list.

If instead you want to remove the prefix which L2 has in common with L1, things get a bit simpler.

```
fun remPref [] _            = []
  | remPref xs []           = xs
  | remPref (x::xs) (y::ys) = if x = y then remPref xs ys else (x::xs)
```

*UPDATE: The question has now been altered.*

If the requirement is now to remove elements from L2 that are in L1, filter is useful.

```
List.filter (fn x => List.all (fn y => x <> y) L1) L2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to compare ROWS, and not single elements of the list.

Comment: Your question never mentioned lists of tuples, but fine, I will adapt my answer. Try to be more exact, though.

Comment: @Sarah Looking at your question it would be better if you defined the list types of the lists to avoid polyEqual warnings.